# This log is mean?

Tags: iis

What does this log mean?

```
+ System 
  - Provider 
   [ Name]  ASP.NET 2.0.50727.0 
  - EventID 1309 
   [ Qualifiers]  32768 
   Level 3 
   Task 3 
   Keywords 0x80000000000000 
  - TimeCreated 
   [ SystemTime]  2011-11-04T03:00:05.000000000Z 
   EventRecordID 1761045 
   Channel C:\Users\log\application.evt 
   Computer aaaa
   Security 

- EventData 
   3005 
   An unhandled exception has occurred. 
   11/4/2011 10:00:05 AM 
   11/4/2011 3:00:05 AM 
   3d6e52ac2e354e6eaa369a9f94bcbba9 
   98 
   3 
   0 
   /LM/W3SVC/366070554/Root-38-129648486871131250 
   Full 
   / 
   D:\wwwroot\pro\ 
   HAMA

   6948 
   w3wp.exe 
   NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE 
   FormatException 
   Input string was not in a correct format. 
   http://pro.com/Popup/ProductPrint.aspx?productId=16294 
   /Popup/ProductPrint.aspx 
   66.249.69.149 

   False 

   NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE 
   9 
   NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE 
   False 
   at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal) at System.Number.ParseDouble(String value, NumberStyles options, NumberFormatInfo numfmt) at System.Double.Parse(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info) at System.Convert.ToDouble(String value) at HuraCommerce.Popup.ProductPrint.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) at System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) at System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) at System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

Answer (score 2):

It means that your ASP.NET script threw an exception error, because the script is attemping to convert a string variable to a number variable, but the input string is not a number, or is formatted incorrectly.

The error occured in the file `/Popup/ProductPrint.aspx`